# Is there a reversible bitwise operation like XOR, except by the fact that the order of the operands matter?

Tags: hash, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I am representing the occurrence of a sequence of events as a very long fixed-size cumulative bit string.
E.g., event A is identified as '010111000110100', event B is identified as '101001110001100'. [Shortened strings for simplicity.]

The sequence A -> B leads to the list of strings ['010111000110100', '101001110001100'].

In my context, such sequence of events can also be seen as a bigger single event by itself, so I am representing it as the result of a XOR operation: '111110110111000'.

XOR is interesting here because it is reversible, so I can undo the last event.
However, A XOR B is the same as B XOR A. The situation is even worse for long sequences, where all event permutations result in the same identifier.

**Is there any way to extend the XOR operation such that it gives different results for different orderings of the same operands (keeping the reversibility property)?**

Another, less elegant solution I thought of was to concatenate both strings and calculate some reversible hash function. But it doesn't seem elegant, nor something with a standard way to approach.

Comment: A reversible operation is symmetric cryptographic encryption. It uses a key and gives a different output for every different input. The length of the output is equal to the length of the input. And you can use the same key to reverse the operation (decryption). Not sure if this helps for your use case. But as XOR is also a (simple) cryptographic operation, this sounds similar. - Another, very simple operation would be +1 (add one), which is also reversible (-1)...

Comment: @lzydrmr This seems the way to go. I am thinking about using both key and input as operands, so it will be easy to revert by just using the last event identifier as key.